# $_GET parameter with no value not responding to isset

Tags: php, get, isset

I am the developer of a WordPress plugin.  The plugin uses the get parameter "podcast" to return a podcast feed; for example, the URL `http://example.com/?podcast` will return the podcast feed.

To do this, the plugin uses this code:

```
//Display the podcast if that's what's requested
if (isset($_GET['podcast']))
    require(SB_INCLUDES_DIR.'/podcast.php');
```

This has been working well.  However, I ran across a site where this is not working.  However, if I add an `=1` to the URL, like `http://example.com/?podcast=1` it works.

Any ideas why this would be the case on that site?  Do different versions of PHP behave differently in this regard, or could it be a security rule on the site that is throwing away parameters with no value?

Comment: Without seeing other's code, I presume it would be something like: If(isset($_GET['podcast'])&&!empty($_GET['podcast']) {}
As for why - I don't know, sorry!

Comment: @Anonymous2011 The other site is using the code I posted, because they are using my plugin.  But it works correctly on every site I've looked at using my plugin except that one.

Comment: @nl-x The plugin is not disabled, because when I specify "podcast=1" in the URL it works correctly.

Comment: You're right. How about some badly written rewrite rule?

Comment: @nl-x That's definitely a possibility.  I'll have to think about how I could talk the user through troubleshooting that.